# Control position of accordion and how it opens when you use an anchor link?

Tags: css, hyperlink, accordion, shortcode

I currently have anchor tags in my main navigational menu, which when clicked will open the corresponding accordion item below. The problem I am having is, when you click on the anchor link, the accordion will open 1/2 way down the inside content, and you cannot see the accordion header/title. It is almost like it opens at the bottom of the content.

Everything seems to work with no problems in Firefox and Chrome, but the dreaded IE will not behave.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

Thanks much!

Jen

Comment: give us some code that shows your problem. I guess you need some extra element in fixed position to avoid ... page jumping ?

Comment: Here is the CSS: .myanchor:before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -285px; 
  height: 285px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
 Here is the rest: <strong id="h9">[su_accordion]</strong>[su_spoiler title="Children's Faith Formation - Catechesis of the Good Shepherd" style="fancy" anchor="Children"]<a class="myanchor" name="Children"></a>Catechesis of the Good Shepherd is a hands-on, experiential method of learning that offers the essentials of our Catholic faith in a way that engages and delights children through presentations rooted in liturgy and scripture....

Comment: I think I am explaining my problem incorrectly (sorry), you can view what I am talking about at http://67.43.3.41/~mmotc/grow-in-faith/ and click on the 4th link under the Grow in Faith menu item. **Note everything works perfect in Firefox and Chrome, you will need to use IE to see the problem.

Comment: I am using shortcode for the accordion, could that be the problem?